# Loop retrieval for multiple excel

Tags: r

I'm trying to use R to create a function with a loop that will retrieve the value of a certain category from excel files. The function takes to arguments. *dado* is the string which it should look for in column two, and coluna is which of the column values it should give back. It looks like this:

```
planilha <- data.frame ()

Dados_depen <- function(dado, coluna) {
  for (i in  1: length(list.files())) {
    estado <- read_excel( list.files()[i], col_names =FALSE)    
    planilha [1, 1] <- "dado"
    planilha [1,i+1] <- subset (estado , estado [,2] == "dado" )[coluna]
    }
  }
```

However, the function is not working though.

Comment: Hi, when you say "not working" what is the error you get? Can you also provide a sample excel file?

Comment: The error message: > Dados_depen( "Estabelecimentos com biblioteca",11)
New names:
* `` -> ...1
* `` -> ...2
* `` -> ...3
* `` -> ...4
* `` -> ...5
* ...
 Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, i + 1, value = list(...11 = "0.375")) : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns

Comment: Have you tried printing some of estado to check if the files are read correctly and it looks as you would expect?  Also a small thing but you don’t need to set planilha[1,1] inside the loop as it doesn’t depend on i.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it. It had two kinds of issues, scoping, and also I was trying to start the data frame from column 2, and it wouldn't let me.